# Передача значений в Thread через цикл for()

Tags: java

Есть следующий код:

```
String[] prop_run;
prop_run[0] = "classA";
prop_run[1] = "classB";
for (int i = 0; i <= prop_run.length; i++) {
    new Thread(() -> RunClassByName(prop_run[i])).start();
}
private static void RunClassByName(String class_name) {
    //...
}
return;
```

Результат:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final
at Main.main(Main.java:24)
```

На 24-ой строке написано следующее: `new Thread(() -> myFunction(prop_run[i])).start();`

Как исправить проблему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так попробуйте. Требуется final переменная для передачи в анонимный класс, который сделает лямбда. Вроде должно сработать.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= prop_run.length; i++) {
    final int j = i;
    new Thread(() -> myFunction(prop_run[j])).start();
}
```

Comment: Да вроде работает, тогда что-то не так со старым вопросом :D

Comment: точнее ответом на вопрос

Comment: лучше строку (параметр метода) final сделать, раз уж такое. Или сразу класс, реализующий Runnable, который будет эту строку принимать в конструкторе

Comment: @zRrr предложите свой вариант. Я в лямбдах не силён, не знаю точно как они работают вообще и с final-ами в частности.

Comment: @Lesperanza Все так. Переменная должна быть объявлена как final или быть effectively final (т.е. фактически не изменяться, верно для Java 8 и выше). Учите матчасть.